# Executing a php file onClick

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, onclick

I currently have a php file executing:

```
<a href="test.php?foo=boo">test</a>
```

I would rather not have to load a new page and do it onClick.

Does anyone know a simple way to do this?

I added a more complete example, including the suggested ajax. I still am having trouble getting it it to work though.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('li').click(function() {
    $.ajax({ type: "GET", url: "test.php", data: { foo: 'boo' }, success: function(data){
          // use this if you want to process the returned data
         alert('complete, returned:' + data);
    }});
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>      
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail?

Comment: He has provided enough I thought. He wants a PHP script to be executed when the link is clicked withought leaving the page.

Comment: what exactly is the problem now? don't you get the alert? doesn't the request fire (use firebug to inspect that)? **EDIT:** i think i found the problem: you have to wrap your code into a domready-handler, otherwise it will be executet before the `li` is loadet and so is doesn't get the click-handler applied. wite: `$(document).ready(function(){ /*your code here*/ });`

Answer (score 5):

Yes, as your tags say. You will need to use AJAX.

For example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test.php",
    data: "foo=boo"
});
```

Then you just have to stick that within a click function.

```
$('a').click(function() {
    // The previous function here...
});
```

**EDIT:** Changed the method to GET.

Comment: why do you set the type to POST? Jon Wilson used a normal link before, wich will result in a get-request.

Comment: Force of habit sorry. I always use post unless I am just retreiving the data from a file. In which case I use get. I will change the example then.

Comment: You don't "need to use ajax" - its a sensible way of solving the problem. Another approach would be to set the location of a (hidden?) iframe.

Answer (score 5):

you could use jquery and do something like this:

```
$.ajax({ url: "test.php", data: { foo: 'boo' }, success: function(data){
      // use this if you want to process the returned data
      // alert('complete, returned:' + data);
    }});
```

for more information, take a look at [the jquery-documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks! I added that but am still having trouble. I modified my example above.

Comment: you have to wrap your code into a domready-handler, otherwise it will be executet before the `li` is loadet and so is doesn't get the click-handler applied. wite: `$(document).ready(function(){ /*your code here*/ });`

Answer (score -4):

In your firl say e.g try.html write this code

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=test.php?foo=boo">
```

it will redirect u to test.php?foo=boo in 2 seconds

OR Other way ===========================================

create one php file

```
<?php
header('Location: test.php?foo=boo');
exit;
?>
```

Hope this help

Comment: this is exactly what Jon Wilson doesn't want. he wanted to process test.php _without_ opening it in the current or another browser window/tab.